# xgettext plural parameter string not extracted to POT

Tags: c#, localization, internationalization, gettext, xgettext

I'm using this C# class in order to internationalize my strings:

```
internal class T
{
    public static string _(string text) { /*...*/ }
    public static string _(string text, params object[] args) { /*...*/ }
    public static string _n(string text, string pluralText, long n) { /*...*/ }
    public static string _n(string text, string pluralText, long n, params object[] args) { /*...*/ }
    public static string _p(string context, string text) { /*...*/ }
    public static string _p(string context, string text, params object[] args) { /*...*/ }
    public static string _pn(string context, string text, string pluralText, long n) { /*...*/ }
    public static string _pn(string context, string text, string pluralText, long n, params object[] args) { /*...*/ }
}
```

I perform for extracting strings: `xgettext -k_ -k_n:1,2
 -k_p:1c,2 -k_pn:1c,2,3 -LC# --omit-header --from-code=UTF-8 -o messages.pot -c
-n -p PO ./TransClassOne.cs`

My `TransClassOne` class is:

```
public class TransClassOne
{

    public string sayHello()
    {
        return Utils.T._("Hello!!");
    }

    public string sayHello(string person)
    {
        return String.Format(Utils.T._("Hello, {0}!!"), person);
    }

    public string sayHello(string person, int n)
    {
        return String.Format(Utils.T._n("Hello, {0} - once!!", "Hello, {0} - twice!!", n), person);
    }

    public string sayGoodBye()
    {
        return Utils.T._("Good Bye!!");
    }

    public string sayGoodBye(string person)
    {
        return String.Format(Utils.T._("Good Bye, {0}!!"), person);
    }

    public string sayGoodBye(string person, int n)
    {
        return String.Format(Utils.T._n("Good Bye, {0} - once!!", "Good Bye, {0} - twice or more!!", n), person);
    }
}
```

The problem is `Hello, {0} - twice or more!!` and `Good Bye, {0} - twice or more` doesn't appear on my `messages.pot` file.

Answer (score 0):

Your command looks good. It could be a bug in the xgettext tool you're using. What version of xgettext are you using? I had a similar problem with `version 0.14`; now I'm using `version 0.19` it's all good. Try downloading it from here https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html